# Why do blanket implementations for two different traits conflict?

Tags: rust, traits

Say I have this code:

```
pub trait A {}
pub trait B {}

pub trait SomeBehavior {
  fn func() -> bool;
}
```

And I want to provide the blanket implementation for `A` and `B` like this:

```
impl <T> SomeBehavior for T where T: A {
  fn func() -> bool { true }
}

impl <T> SomeBehavior for T where T: B {
  fn func() -> bool { false }
}
```

But this gives following error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `SomeBehavior`
  --> src/lib.rs:12:1
   |
8  | impl <T> SomeBehavior for T where T: A {
   | -------------------------------------- first implementation here
...
12 | impl <T> SomeBehavior for T where T: B {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation
```

Why the compiler treats two different implementations on different traits as same implementation?

Comment: What with a type that implements both `A` and `B`, what implementation will it pick?

Comment: _Why the compiler treats two different implementations on different traits as same implementation_ What if `T` implements `A` and `B` at the same time ?

Comment: Well if such type exists the compiler should return an error. But why would the compiler hastily expects that?

Comment: In the general case, it's undecidable for the compiler whether such a type exists, because with genercis there's an infinite number of types, and the implementations of `A` and `B` may depend on complex trait bounds again. The "non-overlapping impls" rule will eventually be relaxed when a feature called "specialization" lands, but my understanding is that your code will be invalid even then. If you want to know more about this topic, search for "rust coherence" in your search engine of choice.

Comment: *"why would the compiler hastily expects that?"* - Rust has taken the stance that generics should be devoid of issues in *principle*, not just in *practice*. So if the compiler sees that two implementations *could* conflict, it will reject that code.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comment.s If you just put your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rust has the concept of "trait coherence" which is the idea that for any combination of type and trait there should be at most *one* implementation of that trait. This is the concept that guides Rust's "orphan rule" and is designed to ensure that conflicting implementations can't occur in downstream crates.

So the problem with the two blanket implementations above is the possibility that a type can implement both `A` and `B`. There would then be *two* possible implementations for `SomeBehavior` for that type.

```
struct MyType;
impl A for MyType;
impl B for MyType;

let t = MyType;
let _ = t.func(); // how to choose?
```

Its not particularly well documented part of Rust unfortunately; likely because its complicated, its contentious, the rules have changed over the years, and will likely change again in the future. Resources are scattered between blog posts, RFCs, and issues but you can find the important bits in the [Coherence](https://rust-lang.github.io/chalk/book/clauses/coherence.html) section of the [chalk](https://github.com/rust-lang/chalk) book (the next-generation trait-solver).

There may be features added in the future that may allow this or something similar:

- [negative impls](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/negative-impls.html) (unstable feature)
- [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) (RFC)
- [crate-level where-clauses](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2022/04/17/coherence-and-crate-level-where-clauses/) (blog article by Niko Matsakis)

Comment: This is a great answer, but how do I work around this? I can a trait have multiple blanket implementations?

Comment: No, a trait cannot have multiple blanket implementations [even when they don't overlap](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20400). Workarounds depend on the use case and could be done via wrapper types, [an extra layer of abstraction](/a/40408431/2189130), or avoid the problem entirely by using separate functions/traits instead of handling everything under one interface.